# Multi-dimensional data plotting

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, sas

I have a dataset in which each observation (identified by ID) has multiple (4+) measures. Each measure has a global cut-off value: one per each measure, and it applies to all observations. I would like to visualize these data points on a graph, including the cut-off values, so that the data points which exceed the cut-off values, can be quickly identified.

On a two-dimensional graph, this can be easily done by a scatter plot and a line which represents the cut-off value, but it does not appear so easy in a multi-dimensional case.

I have already looked into Radar and Polar charts. The problem with them is that each observation (ID) is represented multiple times, so it is difficult to see which points exceed the cut-off value for at least one measure.

```
    ID  Measure         Value
    1   Avg Size        100
    1   Max Throughput  1000
    1   Inc Diff        1.56
    1   Max Value       10000000
    2   Avg Size        150
    2   Max Throughput  1500
    2   Inc Diff        2.4
    2   Max Value       10000000
    3   Avg Size        250
    3   Max Throughput  900
    3   Inc Diff        0.5
    3   Max Value       15000000
```

The technology solution is not particularly relevant. I was trying to accomplish this in SAS; there are a number of interesting JavaScript charting libraries, which would work as well.

I am looking for examples of visualization in multi-dimensional (4+ dimensions) scenarios.

Comment: With multiple measures that are only loosely related, I'd suggest creating a panel, lattice or grid of multiple charts (one or more for each measure).  In SAS you could look at  `proc sgpanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone in your struggle!

This is the simulated data I'm working with:

```
/*Simulate reproducible random data. Six dimensions.*/
data have;
    do id=1 to 20;
        measure_1 = ceil(ranuni(_N_    )*10   );
        measure_2 = ceil(ranuni(_N_+20 )*100  );
        measure_3 = ceil(ranuni(_N_+40 )*1000 );
        measure_4 = ceil(ranuni(_N_+60 )*10000);
        measure_5 = ceil(ranuni(_N_+80 )*1000 );
        measure_6 = ceil(ranuni(_N_+100)*100  );
        output;
    end;
run;
```

I have not represented the cut-offs, but you could represent a few dimension cut-offs using annotation. Below is a way to at least represent 5 dimensions (ActiveX interactive graph, use IE to view):

```
/*Visually represent 5 of the 6 dimensions, however visualizing the thresholds is hard.*/
data have_prepare;
    set have;
    length measure_3_color $8;
    measure_2_size  = measure_2/50;
    measure_3_color = cats("CX",put((measure_3/1000)*256,hex2.),'FF',put(256-(measure_3/1000)*256,hex2.));
run;

/*Output Java ActiveX graph for user manipulation.*/
ods html file="C:\test_activex.html";
goptions reset=all device=activex 
         border xpixels=600 ypixels=400 
     cback=white;  
title1 "5 dimension representation";
title2 "Measures 4 to 6 are spatial, Measure 2 is shape size, Measure is color";
title3 "Right-click to use the 'Graph Toolbar'";
proc g3d data=have_prepare;
  scatter measure_4*measure_5=measure_6 / noneedle
     color=measure_3_color
     size=measure_2_size
     shape="BALLOON";
run;
quit;
ods html close;
```

[image]

If you're open to a less fancy approach to looking at your data, you could traffic light as many dimensions as you desire using simply `proc print` and `proc format` ([more detail here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/366-2013.pdf)):

```
/*Using PROC PRINT with traffic lighting could work?*/
/*Create formats to color cell backgrounds corresponding to values outside predetermined cut-offs*/
proc format;
    value m1_thresh_bg_fmt  low-8   = 'white'
                            9-high  = 'red';

    value m2_thresh_bg_fmt  low-75  = 'white'
                            76-high = 'red';

    value m3_thresh_bg_fmt  low-100  = 'CX0000FF' /*blue*/
                            101-900  = 'CXFFFFFF' /*white*/
                            901-high = 'CXFF0000' /*red*/;

    value m4_thresh_bg_fmt  low-2000  = 'red'
                            2001-high = 'white';

    value m5_thresh_bg_fmt  low-60  = 'red'
                            61-high = 'white';

    value m6_thresh_bg_fmt  low-90  = 'white'
                            91-high = 'red';
run;

ods html file="C:\test_print.html";
proc print data=have noobs;
    var id;
    var measure_1 / style(data)={background=m1_thresh_bg_fmt.};
    var measure_2 / style(data)={background=m2_thresh_bg_fmt.};
    var measure_3 / style(data)={background=m3_thresh_bg_fmt.};
    var measure_4 / style(data)={background=m4_thresh_bg_fmt.};
    var measure_5 / style(data)={background=m5_thresh_bg_fmt.};
    var measure_6 / style(data)={background=m6_thresh_bg_fmt.};
run;
```

[image]